# Eclipse IDE Crash on startup

Tags: android, eclipse, amazon-web-services, eclipse-kepler

I've configured my eclipse(Kepler) IDE to develop Amazon Cloud application and Android applications. When I restarted it to reflect changes it doesn't start. Eclipse window automatically closes after selecting workspace. Earlier It was working well while developing simple Java applications.

My eclipse.ini file looks like this

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20130521-0416
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
 -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=512
-Xms500m
-Xmx512m
```

I think it is something in my eclipse.ini file that is forcing eclipse to Quit. PS. I am using ubuntu Linux 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should change your workspace. I had a similar problem, after saving some code, i closed it and the next time i tried to start it, it just crashed.

So i changed my workspace to another folder and it worked.

If by this method your eclipse works, then just create a new project and paste the code from the previous project in this one.

Do not try to import the previous project, as that has been corrupted and hence is forcing eclipse to quit. Just copy and paste the code and then delete the previous workspace.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I've tried changing workspaces, same problem.  Do you think all parameters in  eclipse.ini have correct value ?