# Eclipse(Android Bundle) Crashing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ubuntu

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04. Since then Eclipse has been crashing. The message is

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x734be86d, pid=7930, tid=3076015872
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_05-b13) (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.5-b02 mixed mode linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x5486d]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x1d
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/funcoding/Android Development/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/eclipse/hs_err_pid7930.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I also tried adding `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla"` to eclipse.ini

**Update:** I tried many things but keeps on crashing unexpectedly. Finally I have decided to stick with Android Studio(Running smoothly as of now).

Comment: check this-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540354/eclipse-ide-crash-on-startup/22540524#22540524

Answer (score 27):

This is just a temporary fix, and I am sure it won't be selected as an answer, but I am putting this here so that anyone with this problem can at least continue to use eclipse until a better solution is found.

Tool tips appear to be causing the problem so I disabled them. I am able to continue programming and I haven't had it crash on me again (yet).

To disable tool tips go to Windows>Preferences>Java>Editor>Hovers and deselect all of the text hover key modifier preferences.

I hope this helps.

edit:

It also crashes when eclipse tries to content assist users. To disable this go to Windows>Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist. Scroll down to Auto Activation and disable auto activation

Comment: You are definitely right, it crashes every time it pops up the suggestions for the signature of the method I'm calling... don't know how to disable that though

Comment: thx it works! Anyway isn't there a fix yet? without content assist it really feels like gedit

Comment: for me it just does the javascript editor, other hovers are fine

Comment: disabling the setting can avoid crashing, however, an IDE without auto complete is terrible!!

Answer (score 24):

This bug has been reported here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404776

Fix described in comments that works for me too is to add this line at the end of your eclipse.ini file

-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla

Comment: This also works for other programs that use java and libsoup. For me this fixed a problem I had with CrashPlanDesktop.

Comment: This is a different bug. It won't fix the issue with adt-bundle in ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: This also worked with the Pentaho Spoon GUI (Version 5.0.1). I just had to add the `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla` to the end of the `OPT` variable (line 188) of script `spoon.sh`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's pretty strange that this works work for me when I launch Eclipse from command line. If I use the shortcut on Ubuntu Launcher, it still crashes every time the auto complete pops up.

Comment: For all those who use Ubuntu 14.04 or Ubuntu, I suggest you use the solution in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516589/eclipse-crashed-on-ubuntu-14-04. This really solves me issue, now I don't crash even when launching Eclipse from Ubuntu launcher! Btw, I use latest ADT Bundle from google.

Comment: This totally worked for me. Kubuntu 14.04, Android Developer Tools Build: v22.3.0-887826, eclipse: 4.2.1

Answer (score 7):

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and was getting this with the Android ADT bundle of eclipse.  Installing eclipse via the Ubuntu Software Center and then installing ADT via the directions linked below worked for me.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Answer (score 1):

this is probably not the smartest solution but it definitely solved my problems:

after playing with eclipse.ini parameters I asked to a friend of mine to give me his eclipse.ini based on Kepler and I found out that some packages invoked in the startup were newer than the ones that come with the ADT bundle.

So I:

1) installed a fresh copy of Kepler
2) used the Android update site to add the android framework
3) after rebooting it asked me to update the Android SDK

So far I didn't have any crash (autocompletion etc.) so it seems it solved the problem...

hope that helps

Luca

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall eclipse.

I had got this problem after upgrading to 14.04. I downloaded the latest JRE, it didn't work.
Then I got the latest eclipse and now it works.

Comment: I shall try it and let you know. I found an alternative by installing Android Studio

Comment: Are you sure new 14.04 requires a minimum version of Eclipse? If so, what version are you using that works?