# eclipse crashed on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-14.04

i used google android ide adt-eclipse on ubuntu 13.10.it was fine. when i upgrade the ubuntu 14.04.the eclipse is crashed when it was clued to method or etc.the log is follow:
who can help me ? thanks!

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f3d9fbaa685, pid=29310, tid=139905366640384
#
# JRE version: 7.0_15-b03
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0+0x407685]  webkitWebViewRegisterForIconNotification+0x95
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f3e38009800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=29318, stack(0x00007f3e419e4000,0x00007f3e41ae5000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000005f38

Registers:
RAX=0x00007f3e41ae23e0, RBX=0x00007f3e3a5fb330, RCX=0x00007f3e2e6f7f00, RDX=0x00007f3e3a5fb330
RSP=0x00007f3e41ae2348, RBP=0x00007f3e3a5c8db0, RSI=0x00007f3d9fb82e50, RDI=0x0000000000005ec8
R8 =0x00007f3e382879e0, R9 =0x0000000000000020, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x0000000000000033
R12=0x00007f3e2e9ae940, R13=0x00007f3e382a1200, R14=0x00007f3e3a4178b0, R15=0x00007f3e3a5c8db0
RIP=0x00007f3d9fbaa685, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e
```

Comment: Why it is tagged `ubuntu-14.04` in question it is said about `ubuntu-13.10`

Comment: now the ubuntu version is 14.04.before upgradding ,it's 13.10.the error is occured on 14.04

Answer (score 23):

You might want to try adding

```
org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

to `configuration/config.ini`

(from https://askubuntu.com/questions/457506)

Comment: i did it.but it was not useful

Comment: add the above lines to eclipse.ini file and not configuration/config.ini

Comment: Adding this to the config.init file looks like the correct answer; eclipse kept on crashing with Ubuntu 14 every 5 minutes, and it's now running flawlessly for 1 hour, so it looks like it's the good trick ! Thanks !

Comment: This really works for me. If I put the setting in eclipse.ini, it only works when launching from cmd line. But then it still keep crashing when launching Eclipse from Ubuntu Launcher. That sucks. With this solution, I can launch Eclipse from launcher without crashing whenever auto complete pops up. Big thanks!! Btw, I am using the latest ADT Bundle!

Comment: what if I unistalled mozilla firefox and use Opera as my default browser? Should I use the same code?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem for couple of weeks now. Adding the following line to the `eclipse.ini` file has solved my problem. Give it a try and hope it helps.

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 1.7 java, please confirm

Project-> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Compiler Compliance level is 1.7 and:

```
SET -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
```

in `ECLIPSE.INI`.