# eclipse IDE crashes in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

after starting my eclipse crashed always and a log file is created in directory which is below : please help me

```
    #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fc0af6742a1, pid=8626, tid=140467226240768
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_65-b17) (build 1.7.0_65-b17)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6c2a1]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x11
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Comment: Could be Eclipse bug [404776](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404776) or one of the many duplicates. Should be fixed in Eclipse 4.4 or there are workarounds listed in the bug report.

Comment: possible dupplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516589/eclipse-crashed-on-ubuntu-14-04