# Tired with reopen Eclipse

Tags: java, android, c, eclipse

I use Eclipse for developing Android Application. I used `adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702` for sdk bundle with eclipse. And In my application I used NDK which is `android-ndk-r9d`. If I used **ctrl+space** in Java Editor I faced the following problem,

1. the tip menu is shown and in the mean while Eclipse also closed.
2. If i open the eclipse again means my entire application shown with an error. In this condition I need to restart eclipse again. If I restart the eclipse the error is gone.
3. But In C Editor it works perfectly

And In **Eclipse** log I got the following error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x6396286d, pid=3861, tid=3076306688
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_11-b12) (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.11-b03 mixed mode linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x5486d]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x1d
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

And I followed this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457506/eclipse-adt-crash-failed-to-write-core-dump-core-dumps-have-been-disabled) But its no help to me :(.. Can anyone give some suggestion about it..

Comment: Did you try different JRE? If I recall correctly, IcedTea/OpenJDK worked very well for me. Though currently I also use Oracle's 1.8 JRE, though on x64 architecture.

Comment: I would also try a different JRE first, also have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172416/eclipseandroid-bundle-crashing

Comment: @Marius I also update 1.7 to Oracle's 1.8 JRE but its also not give the solution for it.. And I have 32 bit

Comment: @UdoKlimaschewski i followed this link It didn't solve :(

Comment: if I were I would just stop using eclipse and migrating to AndroidStudio. Google is slowly and steadily dropping support for Eclipse and it's likely your particular issue will never be solved. Meanwhile AndroidStudio is getting better every week. EDIT: yes, Android Studio already supports NDK builds.

Comment: @Budius Too bad, AndroidStudio is officially still Beta. For learning purposes it's good, but on Eclipse I can work on same project on several computers or with several people, while AndroidStudio fails to import any project with default settings.

Comment: @Marius I respectfully disagree. Yes, there's a beta tag on it. But I work here with 3 other developers and one integration server syncing all through github and still works much better than Eclipse ever did. The day I had to work from home was just a matter of git-clone and import and it worked. It was like you're saying about an year ago when they started the developer previews. But nowadays it's a totally different story.

Comment: @Budius I'm glad it works for you. Several weeks ago I created a project using AndroidStudio at work(Windows 7, Oracle JDK 8). It generated .gitignore files, everything was working like, and IDE itself felt nicer than Eclipse. Several days later, I cloned project on my home computer(Ubuntu 14.04, Oracle JDK 8) and couldn't import it. I've tried it few months ago with similarly bad luck. I guess I'll try it again in few month. Opposite happened with Android L - some people find it buggy and unusable, though it works even better than KitKat for me.

Comment: the link in question worked for me